# how to convert mix date formats mm-dd-yyyy and yyyy-mm-dd to date in pandas

Tags: python

I am reading multiple csv files in pandas each has different date formats

```
  df1
  Trans_Date              Value
  28-02-2018 02:19:00     123478
  24-02-2018 03:29:00     4456
  21-02-2018 04:22:00     5567
  01-03-2018 02:34:00     435
  02-03-2018 10:19:00     4567
```

I am converting `Trans_Date` to `datetime` with following function in pandas

```
 df['Trans_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.Trans_Date)
```

It's giving me following output

```
  Trans_Date              Value
  2018-02-28 02:19:00     123478
  2018-02-24 03:29:00     4456
  2018-02-21 04:22:00     5567
  2018-01-03 02:34:00     435
  2018-02-03 10:19:00     4567
```

For last two observations its doing incorrect conversion. I am not able to figure out why.

Help would be appriciated.

Comment: Just pass a format string to `to_datetime` rather than rely on it guessing

Comment: There are two possible conversions for the last two rows, it picks the wrong one. You need to do a conversion where you can instruct it which format the input has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dayfirst=True`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Trans_Date': ["28-02-2018 02:19:00", "24-02-2018 03:29:00", "21-02-2018 04:22:00", "01-03-2018 02:34:00", "02-03-2018 10:19:00"]})
print(pd.to_datetime(df.Trans_Date, dayfirst=True))
```

**Output:**

```
0   2018-02-28 02:19:00
1   2018-02-24 03:29:00
2   2018-02-21 04:22:00
3   2018-03-01 02:34:00
4   2018-03-02 10:19:00
Name: Trans_Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```